# Scrapy .css select only on div element with no attributes

Tags: jquery, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm trying to obtain div elements that have no attributes attached to them for example:-

```
<div class="test">
    <div>test</div>
    <div class="inside">test2</div>
    <div>test3</div>
    <div class="hello">test4</div>
    <div>test5</div>
    <div>test6</div>
</div>
```

As a result of the scrapy selector I want the following result.

```
[test, test3, test5, test6]
```

A simple div selector doesn't work. So how do I got forward from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with CSS `:not` selector;

```
div {
  background: red;
}

div:not([class]) {
  background: green;
}
```

Like this, any div without a class will be green.

[View on Codepen](https://codepen.io/Yuschick/pen/vpMeOd)

Answer (score 2):

I think there isn't a way to get that with only `css` selector, but you can use `xpath` also with `scrapy`:

```
response.xpath('//div[not(@*)]')
```